# Is there an elegant way to apply a function over an xarray dimension based on a coordinate value?

Tags: python-xarray

The xarray.apply_ufunc allows me to map a function with arguments over the data variables, however I haven't been able to make the arguments dependent on an xarray coordinate.
I have made a workaround by converting the array to numpy and reconstruct the xarray

```
    import xarray as xr
    import numpy as np
    # create a small xarray
    data = xr.DataArray(np.random.randn(4, 3), dims=("x", "y"), coords={"x": [0, 1, 2, 3]})

    # add a coordinate to this array with shifts to apply to each rows
    data=data.assign_coords(shift=('x', [1,1,2,0]))
    print(data)
```

```
<xarray.DataArray (x: 4, y: 3)>
array([[ 1.66474014,  0.59244195, -2.30255789],
       [-0.0252584 ,  0.24441252,  1.21868344],
       [ 1.10716318,  0.03254358,  0.3009372 ],
       [ 0.15047633, -1.22922668,  2.56393195]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 0 1 2 3
    shift    (x) int64 1 1 2 0
Dimensions without coordinates: y
```

```
    # define a function to apply function:

    def apply_f(func,arr,dim,coord):
        arr_np=[]
        for x,y in arr.groupby(dim):
            arg0 = arr[dim][arr[dim]==x][coord].item()
            arr_np.append(func(y.data,arg0))
        return xr.Dataset({'data': (list(arr.dims),  np.array(arr_np))},coords=arr.coords)

    # Apply this function
    out=apply_f(np.roll,data,'x','shift')

    print(out.data)
```

```
<xarray.DataArray 'data' (x: 4, y: 3)>
array([[-2.30255789,  1.66474014,  0.59244195],
       [ 1.21868344, -0.0252584 ,  0.24441252],
       [ 0.03254358,  0.3009372 ,  1.10716318],
       [ 0.15047633, -1.22922668,  2.56393195]])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 0 1 2 3
    shift    (x) int64 1 1 2 0
Dimensions without coordinates: y
```

Is there a way to do this with xarray.apply_ufunc for example?